# I am trying to paste a certain formula in specified range in all selected sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get the value from a cell in each selected sheet and use it in a formula I would need to paste in that same sheet. The code should look like as the following

```
Sub Copy_Value_in_Cells()


        Dim Wb As Workbook
        Dim Sht As Worksheet
        Dim mySelectedSheets As Sheets
        Dim CompanyCell As Range
        Dim CompanyName As String


        Set Wb = ThisWorkbook


        Set mySelectedSheets = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets


            For Each Sht In mySelectedSheets

                Set CompanyCell = Range("H2")


                For Each CompanyCell In Sht


                CompanyName = CompanyCell.Value

                'use the string CompanyName from CompanyCell in a IF fomula which I want it to be paste in range B20
                Range("B20").Value = "if(B21=CompanyName,True,False)"
                Next
            Next

        Application.CutCopyMode = False


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
Range("B20").Value = "if(B21=CompanyName,True,False)"
```

To

```
Range("B20").Formula = "=if(B21=""" & CompanyName & """,True,False)"
```

The strange triple-quotes are because to include a quote in a string, you need to double it:  e.g. `Msgbox "Your username is ""Alessio_110"""` will display a messagebox with this text:

> Your username is "Alessio_110"

So, if `CompanyName = "Pear Calculators"`, then `Range("B20").Formula = "=if(B21=""" & CompanyName & """,True,False)"` will set the formula to `=if(B21="Pear Calculators",True,False)`

(Of course, `=if(B21="Pear Calculators",True,False)` is the same result as just writing `=(B21="Pear Calculators")`)

Comment: Hi, I receive the Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. How do I identify which object is it?

Comment: @Alessio_110 I suspect the line `For Each CompanyCell In Sht` - because `Sht` is a `Workbook`, not a `Range` or `Collection`.  You could use `Sht.Cells`, but that would be *every* cell in the worksheet.  I don't think you actually need the second `For Each` loop at all.

Comment: Removing the line `For Each CompanyCell In Sht` and its related Next, the code works but only for sheet1 even though I have selected sheet2 and Sheet3 on my excel

Comment: @Alessio_110 That's because you haven't Fully Qualified your Ranges:  e.g. `Sht.Range("B20")` instead of `Range("B20")`, which is in the ActiveSheet

Comment: Fantastic, it is golden.